# Typescript import - relative references must start with

Tags: typescript, import

I am trying to use some node_modules from typescript and then use them in javascript for a visual studio 2022 project.

I have added the module like this

```
npm i @microsoft/dotnet-js-interop
```

in my Typescript file I import like this

```
import { DotNet } from '@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop'
```

When the module is transpiled to javascript the exact some text is used in the .js file

```
import { DotNet } from '@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop';
```

But the browser complains that

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/dotnet-js-interop". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

I know I am missing something but I don't know where to look to find the answer. Why does the visual studio typescript compiler not convert it to a relative path. I assume I don't need to manually do this?

I have tried using paths with the typescript modules but it then says it cant find the module and no .JS file is produced.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2015",    
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/*"
  ]
}
```

Chris

Comment: More searching and I found this - it talks about WebPack

https://medium.com/jspoint/integrating-typescript-with-webpack-4534e840a02b

Hopefully this will solve my issue.